# Laravel generators not added from composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm running a server on CentOS 6.5 and Windows 8. Both are missing the artisan generators namespace.

I've tried running the update multiple times on both machines, but the generators command never shows.

Currently using `"way/generators": "dev-master"` in my composer.json file under `"require-dev"` (also tried under `"require"`). No errors given during the update.

Any ideas on the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add this:

```
'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
```

To your app/config/app.php in the ServiceProviders array.